# Using a variable to cause the exporting of specific rows of a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What is the formula to use a variable to cause the exporting of specific rows of a spreadsheet? For example, if I have a list of employees, and I want only the currently employed on a separate sheet, could I write a formula that if there's a box, say, at the end of each row which is marked currently employed/unemployed, rows that are marked employed, export to another sheet? (I'm no programmer, so I won't understand very technical language.)

Comment: [Filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) maybe?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes, that's pretty helpful. Is there a way to use the filter to send the information to a separate sheet?

Comment: Put the filter function in the other sheet? Did you follow the link I provided?

Comment: @cybernetic-nomad I'm not clear on how to use the filter to export to another sheet? It discusses creating separate cells seemingly in the same sheet?

Comment: "Export" implies a "push" mode of operating - I have something in one range of cells/worksheet/workbook and I some processed version of that something to be placed in another range of cells/worksheet/workbook. In the main, Excel doesn't work like that. Rather it operates, in the main, through a "pull" mode - I am going to perform some processing in this range of cells/worksheet/workbook to get the results of that processing on something stored in another range of cells/worksheet/workbook....

Comment: ... This means that you need to learn how to reference cells within your formulas (such as one containing the FILTER function) that are within a different worksheet (or even workbook). It is not difficult to do, and it really is a fundamental bit of knowledge for using Excel effectively. Try searching for "working with more than one worksheet in Excel".

Comment: @bensvenssohn send the information to a separate sheet?  >> use the formula on the target sheet, but keep the reference to the original sheet.. try this : put '=Sheet1!A1' in Sheet2 A1 cell.. the formula works just fine

Comment: The good old Advanced Filter function might be what you need. You can easily set up a target sheet to only bring across the columns you need, and apply a filter. Really easy to build into a macro (start by recording your actions) to have the empty template target sheet copied to a new workbook then push the data to it before saving.